# C pointer assignment in array

Tags: c, pointers, scope, memory-address

```
typedef struct {
    int head
} List;

List* array[10];
int size = 0;

List* create() {

    if(size < 10){

        List list1;
        list1.head = size;
        array[size] = &list1;
        printf("%d \n", array[size]->head); //value is stored perfectly here
        printf("%p \n", array[size]);       //same value printed everytime (e.g 0x7ffeee1139f0 )
        return array[size++];
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    List* plist1 = List_create();
    printf("%p \n", plist1);//same value 0x7ffeee1139f0

    List* plist2 = List_create();
    printf("%p \n", plist2);//same value 0x7ffeee1139f0
}
```

For the following code above, when I try to iterate over the array and print the value at each index, which should be the address of each list struct I created and hence should be unique.

But I get the same address stored at each index of the array.
I can't figure out why.

Also when I iterate over the array and print array[index]->head, I get some garbage value(e.g. -477361872).

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Inian Sorry, I think it was a typo in my question. I corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are storing the address of a variable on the stack into the array. There is only one stack variable (`list1`) and so its addresss is the same every time. Or it might be different, but there is really ever only one valid `list1` object.

You also should not use stack addresses after they have gone out of scope. So as soon as you leave the `create` function, the addresses you have stored in your array are invalid.

If you want to create an array of ten structs, you can do `List array[10];`. If you want to dynamically allocate each struct, you can use `List *array[10];` and then assign into the array pointers you have allocated using `new` or `malloc` (or other valid pointers).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I could but I am limited to not use malloc or new.

Comment: Are you able to use a stack allocated array of List objects, e.g. `List array[10];`? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The both calls of the function `create` stores the address of the same local variable `list1` in the array `array` and return this address to the caller.

```
List* create() {
    List list1;
    //...
    array[size] = &list1;
    //..
    return array[size++];
    //...
}
```

So the both pointers in main `plist1` and `plist2` have the same invalid values because the local variable `list1` is not alive outside the function `create`.

You should allocate memory for objects of the type `List` dynamically.

For example

```
List* create() {

    if(size < 10){

        List *list1 = malloc( sizeof( List ) );

        if ( list1 != NULL )
        {
            list1->head = size;
            array[size] = list1;
            printf("%d \n", array[size]->head);
            printf("%p \n", ( void * )array[size]);
            return array[size++];
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

In this case you should not forget to free the allocated memory when it will not anymore needed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the loopholes of the C programming language is that you can return a pointer to a local variable from a function. This is what is happening in the function *create*. The next time the function is called the value of the variable *list1* is undefined. If you cannot use dynamic memory allocation, why not simply declare an array of lists instead of list pointers?